# paypal API : How do I get scope response?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am making login process using paypal now and I do not know how to get user information that I asked using 'scopes'.
I made button with this(*) and the process working perfectly. It finally ends at redirect_uri but do not know how do I get email address. I am using PHP. How can I get this value? Anyone knows?

- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect?flowEntry=static&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&scope=openId email&redirect_uri=MY_URI"

Ps.Sorry for my bad grammer.

Comment: For more information, page has been redirected to 'MY_REDIRECT_URI&code=C21AAI11iNrs8SXydSFjqfNzcNf9l4wVDxMyL8i9UQEMs7u_m9_Jxmzf1bKHBOZ247RQr_bjnQhtq0BD1dNRrAPDWKNfDJgmQ&scope=openId%20email' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

After login, exchange the returned authorization_code for an access_token, and use that access_token to get customer information.

See the detailed steps in the [Log in With PayPal integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/#get-access-token).